# Setting DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex stops Timer from firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview, timer

Ok, new puzzle!  Very simple proof-of-concept setup:  `DataGridView`, bound via a `DataTable` to a SQL view.  Data is dynamic (though # of rows is constant), so I added a `Forms.Timer` to refresh it:

```
private DataTable   tbData= new DataTable( );

private void    frmMain_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    LoadData( );
    oTimer.Start( );
    MessageBox.Show( oTimer.Enabled.ToString( ) );
}
private void    frmMain_DoubleClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    LoadData( );    // to reload on-demand - works perfectly
}
private void    LoadData( )
{
    SqlDataAdapter  da=
        new SqlDataAdapter( "select * from vwOne", Program.oSqlConn );

    tbData.Clear( );
    da.Fill( tbData );
    dgView.DataSource=  tbData;
}
private void    oTimer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    LoadData( );
    this.Text+= "|";
}
```

To maintain the scrolling position during refreshes I added the following lines (1 and 2):

```
private void    LoadData( )
{
    SqlDataAdapter  da=
        new SqlDataAdapter( "select * from vwOne", Program.oSqlConn );

    int iRow=   dgView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex; // 1-remember row

    tbData.Clear( );
    da.Fill( tbData );
    dgView.DataSource=  tbData;

    dgView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex=     iRow;   // 2-restore back
}
```

So far so good.  Now here's the kicker:  **without line 2 reload works perfectly (not retaining scroll), but as soon as I uncomment line 2 Timer just stops (breakpoint in oTimer_Tick is never hit)!?**

What gives!?

Edit:  `frmMain_DoubleClick(..)` added to the code above (already had it, and been using), it works properly;  *there are absolutely no exceptions thrown and no issues with SQL connection*.  Literally, uncommenting that line (#2) makes entire difference, observed in oTimer_Tick not being called at all!

Following the suggestions (thank you guys!) i added couple new lines:

- frmMain_Load(..) showing oTimer.Enabled and confirming it finished to the end,
- and appending a '|' to form's title each time oTimer_Tick(..) fires.

Without line 2 execution goes as expected:  message-box says 'True' and title keeps growing with new '|'s.  Uncomment line 2 and .. no message-box!?, no title updates, but no exceptions whatsoever!?  This is run directly from VS2010 in Debug mode, *could the debugger swallow any exceptions* (i've never seen this)?  Reckon, since no message-box shows up this indicates *the problem is with starting the timer*, => it won't fire.  But like i said, the only change is uncommenting line 2..  How/why does it affect the timer!?

Ok, next thing to try will be avoid recompilation by making a dynamic switch (e.g. via a checkbox) whether to preserve the scroll position or not, with the rest of visualization in place, maybe this will expose smth..

Comment: What is the interval between ticks? You can try to disable the timer before calling LoadData() and reenable it when loading is done.

Comment: Normally 1 sec, but it doesn't really matter:  I tried 5, 10 and 20 - and still no joy.  Data retrieval finishes in .02 sec.  Also tried disabling Timer during dvGrid_Scroll events - no effect.  The strangest is that even a breakpoint is never hit - so it actually is never firing!  But how does a Timer know and care about me setting this ScrollingRowIdx - I've no idea so far..

Comment: For what it is worth I have tried your example and cannot replicate the issue. One difference was that I was using a BindingList of objects as the datasource and adding rows to it, but that shouldn't make a difference. Have you tried stepping through load data to ensure that there is nothing odd happening there? And have you checked to see that your ide isn't hiding any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment so...

Have you put a breakpoint on oTimer.Start()?  Does the first call to LoadData() in frmMain_Load() complete?  Is your connection open?  Perhaps there's an exception that's somehow being swallowed, as David Hall mentioned...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2**:  Well, I finally found the root cause:  with line 2 enabled `oTimer.Start( )` does not get called.  And the reason is that during the very first call to LoadData( ) [from frmMain_Load(..)], line 2 produces an exception (*because initial value of that index is -1, and that's an invalid value to be assigned back*)!  Proper way to preserve the scroll position would be to alter line 2 like this:

```
if(  iRow >= 0  )   dgView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex=     iRow;
```

However the nasty thing is that without adding an explicit try-catch block to LoadData( ) i wouldn't find it!  Looks like **during form initialization / load any exceptions are being silently swallowed!!**  Lesson learned;  but IMHO this is not a good approach taken by Microsoft, as i cannot even rely on VS debugger now to announce the reasonably high-level exceptions which may happen on UI thread in WinForm.

The answer rep goes to @appclay, i'd give it to @David Hall since he was first to hint at the possibility.
Thank you all guys!